# Data lost between steps in pentaho plugin

Tags: plugins, pentaho, records

I face a strange issue of losing data between transformation steps, when pushed in high speed. The details are, we have a requirement to find duplicate by our custom algorithm. As the no of records can be large (several millions), we temporarily write the entire records to lucene indexing as documents. Then after appying the algorithm, duplicate sets are found and written to another lucene index. Now the entire records which is to be pushed to the next step is available in the lucene index as documents. The data is then pushed by using the putRow method in a loop. As the data is pushed in high speed, we found the rows are not completely received in the next step. The loss of data is consistent and the records and fields lost are random. When a Thread.sleep of 50 - 100 milliseconds is used we receive the entire data in the next step. The big concern is that the loss of data is not captured or alerted in any manner. Now my questions are

1. Does the putting of data in putRow ensures the record sent to the next step.
2. If not how to make sure the data is received properly in the subsequent steps.

Any help on this regard is highly appreciated. If required I can provide the code.

Comment: for 2nd point you can use "add value fields changing sequence" step in between 2 step and debug whether data loss is happening or not.

Comment: I infact added my custom plugin after this and tried to print the  row data. The loss of data is consistent and sure.